# checkbox not from php form updating mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried multiple fields to see if database will update when user selects or does't select a check box, in all cases, the value in database was 0 (zero)

I have tried, boolean, tinyint and binary
Everything updates into the database except the items that come up as check boxes.

Could someone please see where I went wrong?.
Thanks

Here is the form

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">First Name</td>
<td width="76%"><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name2" value="<? echo $first_name; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Last Name</td>
<td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<? echo $last_name; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Email Address</td>
<td><input name="email_address" type="text" id="email_address" value="<? echo $email_address; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Phone Number</td>
<td><input name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number" value="<? echo $phone_number; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Age</td>
<td><input name="age" type="int" id="age" value="<? echo $age; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Basketball</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="basketball" type="bool" id="basketball" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Cricket</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cricket" type="bool" id="cricket" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Soccer</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="soccer" type="bool" id="soccer" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Table Tennis</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="table_tennis" type="bool" id="table_tennis" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Volley Ball</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="volley_ball" type="bool" id="volley_ball" value="Volley Ball"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">Information about you:</td>
<td><textarea name="info" id="info"><? echo $info; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 34%">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enlist!"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Most likely the issue is this: checkbox input fields are posted to the server as _arrays_, not as scalar values. This makes sense, since a chackbox input field may contain _multiple values_. You can easily see that when you dump the contents of the $_POST variable. You have to address them accordingly, so different than scalar values.

Comment: Thank you Daniel & Arkascha
Here is the code in the file (register.php) called by first page listed above (join_form.php)
<?

include 'db.php';

// Define post fields into simple variables
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$basketball=$_POST['basketball'];
$cricket=$_POST['cricket'];
$soccer=$_POST['soccer'];
$table_tennis=$_POST['table_tennis'];
$volley_ball=$_POST['volley_ball'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

Comment: Here is balance of the code



// Enter info into the Database.
$info2 = htmlspecialchars($info);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (first_name, last_name, email_address, phone_number, age, basketball, cricket, soccer, table_tennis, volley_ball, info, signup_date)
  VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address', '$phone_number', '$age', '$basketball', '$cricket', '$soccer', '$table_tennis', '$volley_ball','$info2', now())") or die (mysql_error());

?>